# The existence of homotopy

Tags: general-topology

Is every pair of continuous functions $f:[0,2\pi]\to\Bbb R$ and $g:[0,2\pi]\to\Bbb R$ homotopic? I mean the straight line homotopy $F:[0,2\pi]\times[0,1]\to\Bbb R$ defined by $F(\theta,t)=(1-t)\times f(\theta)+t\times g(\theta)$.

Comment: yes, also $\mathbb R$ is convex, hence every function is null-homotopic, and homotopic to every other function.